# Read Excel Files and Only Use Specific Files

Tags: python, excel, printing, xlrd

in my past questions, I've stated that I'm new to python. I've only used it once for work. And yet again, there's a small project I have to do for work.

I have to read an excel file, and in that excel file, there are 3 columns (col1, col2, col3).
There are about 100 rows.

col1 has 2 values A and B.
col2 has values ranging from ONLY 1 - 10.
col3, there are plenty of different values.

But I want my python program to look at each distinct value in col1, and then at each distinct value in col2, and then calculate the avg of all the corresponding values of col3.

Hopefully, the output can look something like this:

```
A - 1 = 2.3
A - 2 = 6.2
A - 3 = 5.7
etc. etc.
B - 1 = 3.5
B - 2 = 4.1
B - 3 = 8.1
etc. etc.
```

I know, it's a lot to ask, but I've done this so far:

```
import xlrd #import package

#opening workbook and reading first sheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook('trend.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

#print sheet name, number of rows and columns
#print sheet.name #print sheet name
#print sheet.nrows #print number of rows
#print sheet.ncols #print number of colums

#print cellname along with value in for loop
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
        print xlrd.cellname(row_index,col_index),'-',
        print sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
```

It started printing all the values within each cell, along with the name and such.
But then I realized it's not doing what it's supposed to really be doing.
And I can't find a proper tutorial on how to do this.

If any of you have any suggestions, I'll appreciate it very much. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('trend.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

unique_combinations = {}

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell_1 = sheet.cell(row_index, 0)
    cell_2 = sheet.cell(row_index, 1)
    cell_3 = sheet.cell(row_index, 2)
    unique_combo = (cell_1.value, int(cell_2.value))
    if unique_combinations.has_key(unique_combo):
        unique_combinations[unique_combo].append(cell_3.value)
    else:
        unique_combinations[unique_combo] = [cell_3.value]

for k in unique_combinations.keys():
    values = unique_combinations[k]
    average = sum(values ) / len(values )
    print '%s - %s = %s' % (k[0], k[1], average)
```

Comment: I see this just prints it out. Is there any way I can make it like.. if this cell(col1) equals to a string, it'll start looking at col2, and then if that cell value equals to a certain string, it'll record all the values of col3 that corresponds and calculate the avg??

Comment: Was busy editing - as you edited your question seconds after i posted original answer :-)

Comment: That means that you're passing an integer to the len() function. Perhaps you typed a 1(one) instead of l(L), let's rename the list (editing now)

Comment: You were right. :) Thank you so much for all the help. It didn't complete everything, but I, hopefully, can take it from here.

Comment: Sorry if I keep bothering you. But is there a way for it to print out all the values of col2, and then the corresponding avg of col3? When I use this, it prints out only a couple of the values.. it looks like this:
`A - 9 = -5.07857142857
B - 3 = 1.15
B - 10 = -6.6125`
However, I know that there are plenty of more values in col2, ranging from 1 to 10.

Comment: The code provided should print a line for each unique combination of col1 & col2. Are you saying it misses out combinations (e.g. no "A - 7" but you're sure it exists), or is it that you want to print a line for each individual value col2? (in which case make "unique_combo = cell_2.value")

Comment: I'm saying that it misses out combinations and I'm sure it exists. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26050/discussion-between-andyhasit-and-chakolatemilk)